Why could Blazor CircuitHandler methods not get called?
I am trying to build a minimal working example of a CircuitHandler in a Blazor server side application but none of the CircuitHandler methods are called. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
I'm developing on macOS Sonoma 14.5 using the .NET SDK Arm64 version 8.0.7.
I have used the dotnet commandline tool (version 8.0.303) to create a new project:
dotnet new blazor -o CircuitHandlerApp

In file MyCircuitHandler.cs I have added a simple CircuitHandler implementation:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;

namespace CircuitHandlerApp;


public class MyCircuitHandler : CircuitHandler
{
    public MyCircuitHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor called.");
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCircuitOpenedAsync called.");
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnConnectionUpAsync called.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnConnectionDownAsync called.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCircuitClosedAsync called.");
        return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);   
    }
}


I have registered the handler in Program.cs like this:
...
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler,MyCircuitHandler>();

var app = builder.Build();
...

In my interpretation of the documentation and other sources that should be enough to see some of the CircuitHandler methods being called. But that does not happen when I run the application and connect to it in the browser.
Also the constructor of MyCircuitHandler only gets called when I directly inject the CircuitHandler into one of the components.
On Github I didn't find any issues that sound similar to this problem and I would think that this feature is too essential that no one would have found a bug here before me. So it is probably more a configuration problem.
I have tried using the .NET 9 Preview but that didn't work either.
Here's the full Program.cs file:
using CircuitHandlerTest;
using CircuitHandlerTest.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents(options =>
    {
        options.DetailedErrors = true;
    });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler, MyCircuitHandler>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


Do you have any interactive routes?  The circuit handier will only be used when there is an interactive page/ component currently rendered

@MisterMagoo, I guess I never tried navigating to a different page and always just opened the /-route. So when I open the Counter or Weather pages from the template project I see some activity in the CircuitHandler. Not the activity I had expected but that is a different problem. Thanks for your comment.

I guess the answer to my question is that the code was not wrong but my expectation that the CircuitHandler would behave like an app lifecycle handler and that a circuit would be opened immediately when the browser connects to the application.
The methods of OnCircuitOpenedAsync and OnConnectionUpAsync of my CircuitHandler implementation were called when I opened the Counter page from the template project. The method OnConnectionDownAsync was called twice after I moved away from the Counter page followed by a call of OnConnectionClosedAsync. The next time I opened the Counter page I would get a different circuit id.
So far I did not find a good explanation in the documentation on what the lifecycle of a circuit is, but seems to be tied to the lifetime of components that actually need a backchannel to the server (like the Counter page).
